# (gcloud.auth.login) Invalid value for property [core/custom_ca_certs_file]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, gcloud

When I try to log in with `gdloud auth login` I get this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.auth.login) Invalid value for property [core/custom_ca_certs_file]: The provided path must exist.`

I am not sure what is the problem as it was working a few hours ago.

I tried to google the issue but I cannot find anything on the exact error.

UPDATE:

I deleted gcloud and installed a new one.
Now `gcloud auth login` redirects me to my browser and I am able to successfully authenticate in the browser. However, in my terminal I get this error:

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /Users/Marcin.Kulik/combined_certs.pem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my update I reinstalled gcloud but was facing a new error when trying to login with `gcloud auth login`:

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /Users/Marcin.Kulik/combined_certs.pem`

I am on Mac so I tried:

`(security find-certificate -a -p ls /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain &&        security find-certificate -a -p ls /Library/Keychains/System.keychain) > $HOME/.mac-ca-roots`

I added `export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="$HOME/.mac-ca-roots"` to my .zshrc file and restarted terminal.

It is working fine now.